# How to prevent context related memory leaks in android

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

While investigating my app's memory usage through Android Studio's `Memory monitor` I realized that there might be some memory leaks, mainly caused (in my opinion, please correct me if wrong) by the progressive increase of `Memory allocated` size that grew from around 30MB to 50MB ,70MB and reaching almost 90MB.

These increases of memory allocation are caused by swiping through tabs (`fragments`) and `Activities`, by going back to initial Activities and so on.

The most straight-forward (or easy I might say) method of locating `Memory leaks` could be (as [this link describes the process](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8) ) checking and analyzing a memory `.hprof` file after `dumping a java memory heap` in Android Studio. With this method I have correctly identified a memory leak as I was declaring a `static context` variable (not proud of it).

Unfortunately, while checking the right tab `LeakedActivites` I noticed that `CatalogActivity` is still present there, therefore there is still a context memory leak occurring regarding `mContext`.

[image]

This time I was unable to identify the memory leak, as I haven't declared any  `mContext` variable. (obviously as it has a depth of 6, it is referring to a global context for that activity)

**How can I identify the memory leak that still occurs? Is the behavior I described in the first paragraph normal?** (progressive increase of memory allocation through time)

**CatalogActivity**:

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidein, R.anim.slideout);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
        context = this;

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        int tabIcon1 = R.drawable.ic_collections_24dp;
        int tabIcon2 = R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp;
        int tabIcon3 = R.drawable.ic_chat__24dp;

        if (tabLayout.getTabAt(0) != null) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcon1);
        }
        if (tabLayout.getTabAt(1) != null) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcon2);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setAlpha(128);
        }
        if (tabLayout.getTabAt(2) != null) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcon3);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setAlpha(128);
        }

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent);
                if (tab.getIcon() != null) {
                    tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    tab.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey);
                if (tab.getIcon() != null) {
                    tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    tab.getIcon().setAlpha(128);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CatalogFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new MyBooksfragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new MyChatsFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.sign_out_menu) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            mFirebaseAuth.signOut();
            loadLogInView();
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadLogInView() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Note: The progressive increase of memory allocation happens when I debug the app with LG G6 (4GB RAM). While using an emulated device Nexus 5, the behavior still occurs but is way diminished (memory allocation starts at 2MB and reaches peak around 5MB).

Comment: im sure there are a lot bitmaps. its maybe funny - but bitmaps make a big memory leak.

Comment: please do not make us have to go to other places to look at your code

Comment: @Peter My app has about 4 `GridViews` each fully populated with bitmaps. Therefore you guessed correctly. But how can I stop memory leaks caused by many bitmaps in `GridView`? I have searched many posts and I haven't came to a good solution

Comment: @TimCastelijns The only reason I used a `gist` was to avoid agglomerating the post. My apologies.

Comment: switchFragment() has no use currently btw, you can call switchContent() directly instead

Comment: `switchFrgament` is a method I forgot to delete, it has no use currently, I am editing the post. Yet the leak is clearly not from there

Comment: @CatalinGhita I believe you are using this https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer. Do you do   `ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);` in `onDestory()`?

Comment: @Raghunandan I forgot to call `ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this)` in the `onDestroy`, you are entirely correct. Yet how would this lead to memory leaks?

Comment: @Raghunandan I forgot to call `ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this) `in the `onDestroy`, you are entirely correct. But after the line the problem persists.

Comment: @CatalinGhita i cannot see anything wrong or i might be missing something. Can you post a sample for me to try?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the memory allocated each time on new fragment created was not discarded on destroy.

The problem was in a list of drawables `ArrayList<Drawable>` , setting to null all the elements of the array in onDestroyView the problem was solved.

I think you should try set to null variables with references to bitmaps in your GridView.

Hope it will help ...

Comment: The memory leaks may be caused by the large amount of bitmaps references  that are not getting removed by the GC. Yet I use a `GridView` that  and not an `ArrayList<Drawable>`. (bitmaps are loaded from the database in the adapter). Is there a way I can cut out  the leaks while using `GridView` ?

Comment: Are you closing the Cursor or whatever are you using to get the bitmaps from the DB ?

Comment: I am only getting URI for those bitmaps (from DB) and I load them with `Picasso` library so therefore the leak shouldn't be from there. I still think that I should somehow manage the populated `GridView` in the `OnDestroy` ( somehow setting all  ImageView`'s bitmaps to null). But I am looking for a more elegant way to do this.